# nest linq query

Tags: linq, nested

I have an xml file that contains a list of items i can deserialize into my list: The class is as follow:

```cs
   [Serializable()]
   public class cls_item
   {
      #region enum
      public enum itemtype
      {
         cash,
         credit,
         check
      }
      #endregion

      #region properties
      public DateTime Date { get; set; }
      public itemtype Type { get; set; }
      public double Value { get; set; }
      #endregion
   }
```

After I load the data, Based on the data receive, I want to do a nested linq query to build a tree displayed as follow:

```
--2005 
 |--January 
   |-- 01/01/2005 
   |-- 01/10/2005 
 |--March
   |-- 03/05/2005
--2010
 |--January
   |-- 01/01/2010
   |-- 01/10/2010
 |--March
   |-- 03/05/2010
...
```

What would be the best and fastest linq query I can do on my data to get the results I want?

I have tried the following:

var grouped = from p in data.items
              group p by new { month = p.Date.Month, year = p.Date.Year } into d 
              select new { dt = string.Format("{0}/{1}", d.Key.month, d.Key.year), count = d.Count() };

but need to have another heiarchy or data, thus I need help on generating a nested Linq query?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Do you have a specific question about a particular problem you are having trying to do this? I recommend checking out the FAQ entry, [What kind of questions can I ask here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)

Comment: Or the short version: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might put you in the right direction:

```
var result = from d in myList
             group d by d.Date.Year into g
             select new
                {
                    Year = g.Key,
                    Months = g.GroupBy (x => x.Date.Month)
                        .Select (x => new {Month=x.Key, Dates=x.Select (y => y.Date)})
                };
```

Comment: for the actual date heirarchy, I just need to add a Distinct because I will have multiple items within the same day, where would I add the DISTINCT()?

Comment: append it to `Dates=x.Select (y => y.Date)` on the last line.  It becomes `Dates=x.Select (y => y.Date).Distinct()`